# Ionic - Fixed div scrolling inside ion-content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic3

After GoogleChrome update, a `fixed` div is scrolling with the page.

Sample: [LINK](https://denibelotti.fee.engaged-development.com/turma/as-cinco-linguagens-do-amor/turma-nova-em-dev)

In this case, the MAP is a `fixed` div inside `ion-content`.

If I put a simple div like bellow inside ion-content, it does not stay fixed, but if I move outside the `ion-content` it gets fixed!

```
<div style="width: 100px;height: 100px;position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0px; z-index: 500; background-color: blue;"></div>
```

How to make it FIXED inside `ion-content`?

Thanks for help me!

**I am using Ionic 3(3.20.0)**

Answer (score 1):

You should work with `ion-toolbar` in your Header or Footer. Something like this (I tried it in [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/)):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>My Toolbar Title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>

  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer no-border>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>I'm a footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-footer>
```

Comment: I am currently using `ion-toolbar`. The problem only occurs in Chrome, In other browsers everything is fine!